# How to pass a state changing function to a component, and then pass that state to a parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-typescript

I have a `<Providers>` functional component wrapped around all other app components, to provide necessary "Context" to everything. I need to create a UI component that sets a variable from the user, and have that changed variable passed back up to the `<Providers>` component. The code looks something like this:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [variable, setVariable] = useState(3) // The variable will be a number

  return (
    <Providers variable={variable}>
      <Router>
        <VariableChangingComponent changeVariable={setVariable} />
      </Router>
    </Providers>
  )
}

const Providers: React.FC = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <SomeProvider variableNumber={props.variable}>
      <AnotherProvider>{children}</AnotherProvider>
    </SomeProvider>
  )
}
```

Sorry this is so vague, I don't know what the best approach for this should be. I thought I could use `UseState()` to declare the variable, and then pass that `setVariable` function to the UI component, where I could use it to change the state of `variable` and then pass that down to the `<Providers>` component. Does that make any sense? Or should I do this some other way?

I'm also getting a `Property 'variable' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.` Typescript error. I don't know how to declare the types for the Providers props (I'm new to Typescript).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: See [using context and provider- React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: Yes, it's called "lifting state up" and is [part of the official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you just use `React.FC` without setting a generic for the props type then it doesn't allow you to use any props other than `children` and the props in `IntrinsicAttributes`.

You need to declare that your `Providers` component requires a prop `variable` which is a `number`.  I am also destructuring it rather than using `props.variable`, but that doesn't actually matter.

```
const Providers: React.FC<{variable: number}> = ({ children, variable }) => {
  return (
    <SomeProvider variableNumber={variable}>
      <AnotherProvider>{children}</AnotherProvider>
    </SomeProvider>
  )
}
```

I declared the type for the props object inline since we only have one prop here. You can also make an named type or interface for the props like this:

```
interface ProvidersProps {
  variable: number;
}

const Providers: React.FC<ProvidersProps> = ({ children, variable }) => {
...
```